# Ckeditor keypress keydown events

Tags: ckeditor

I really need some help, I can't figure out how to handle keypress/keydown events.
I've already tried everything and looked into javascript API documentation and here on forum but I couldn't find any solution.

Can someone please explain the right way to do that?
So my question is... how do I get key events working ?

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to listen to [`editor#key`](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.editor-event-key) event. Just like so:

```
var editor = CKEDITOR.instances.editor1;
editor.on( 'key', function( evt ) { console.log( evt ); } );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
CKEDITOR.replace("Instance_Name");

// Function for keypress/keyup:- 

CKEDITOR.instances['Instance_Name'].on("instanceReady", function (event) {
  this.document.on("keyup", function (event) {
    var inputText = CKEDITOR.instances.Instance_Name.getData();
    console.log(inputText);
  });
});
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.